# Solve nonlinear differential equation system - Plot

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics

When I solve the system of differential equations I get two solutions for each variable (See the picture). My question is how I can neglect one of the solutions at the plot. Thanks.

Code:

```
[![\text{Plot}\left\[\text{Evaluate}\left\[\left\{\sqrt{y(x)},z(x)\right\}\text{/.}\, \%\right\],\{x,0,60\},\text{PlotRange}\to \text{All},\text{PlotPoints}\to 200\right\] \left(\text{sol}=\text{NDSolve}\left\[\left\{3 y(x)-0.5 z(x)^2=y(x) (9 \eta  y(x)+0.5) z'(x)^2\text{/.}\, \eta \to 1,-y'(x)=-\eta  y(x) y'(x) z'(x)^2+(4 \alpha +18) \eta  y(x)^2 z'(x)^2+y(x) z'(x)^2\text{/.}\, \{\eta \to 1,\alpha \to 1\},y(0)=1,z(0)=0.2\right\},\{z,y\},\{x,0,60\}\right\]\right)][1]][1]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Replace the `%` with `sol[[1]]` to take the first part?  Hard to check without code that can be copied.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!